# How to keep only 'cells' that have a specific text on a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd love to know if it's possible to keep only 'cells' that have a specific text in a dataframe for example if I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['12hello2', '12hey2', 'hello', '12hey2', '1hello'], ['12hey2', '12hey2', 'hello', '1hello', '1hello'], ['12hey2', '12hey2', 'hello', '1hello', '1hello']]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c','d','e'])
```

How could I delete everything except the 'cells' that contain the string 'hello'? I know how to do this for specific columns or specific rows, but can't figure out how to do it for both so I'm only left with the instances where 'hello' is in the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest I can think of is to filter by columns with `apply` and then `where` to mask:

```
df.where(df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('hello')))
```

Output:

```
          a    b      c       d       e
0  12hello2  NaN  hello     NaN  1hello
1       NaN  NaN  hello  1hello  1hello
2       NaN  NaN  hello  1hello  1hello
```

Comment: `df[df.applymap(lambda x: 'hello' in x)]` is easier ;)

Comment: In this case yes. In general, i think `apply` is a little faster than `applymap` if the function is vectorized.

Answer (score 2):

#### Using `replace`

```
df[df.replace('.*hello.*', 'hello', regex=True).eq('hello')]

          a    b      c       d       e
0  12hello2  NaN  hello     NaN  1hello
1       NaN  NaN  hello  1hello  1hello
2       NaN  NaN  hello  1hello  1hello
​
```

---

#### `stack`/`unstack`

```
df[df.stack().str.contains('hello').unstack()]

          a    b      c       d       e
0  12hello2  NaN  hello     NaN  1hello
1       NaN  NaN  hello  1hello  1hello
2       NaN  NaN  hello  1hello  1hello
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like `replace`

```
df.replace({"^(.(?<!hello))*?$":np.nan},regex=True)
          a   b      c       d       e
0  12hello2 NaN  hello     NaN  1hello
1       NaN NaN  hello  1hello  1hello
2       NaN NaN  hello  1hello  1hello
```